# SQL: Generate Record Per Month In Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which describes a value which is valid for a certain period of days / months.
The table looks like this:

```
+----+------------+------------+-------+
| Id |    From    |     To     | Value |
+----+------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-03-31 | ValA  |
|  2 | 2018-01-16 | NULL       | ValB  |
|  3 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-05-12 | ValC  |
+----+------------+------------+-------+
```

As you can see, the only value still valid on this day is ValB (To is nullable, From isn't).

I am trying to achieve a view on this table like this (assuming I render this view someday in july 2018):

```
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
| RecordId |    From    |     To     | Value |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
|        1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 | ValA  |
|        1 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-28 | ValA  |
|        1 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-31 | ValA  |
|        2 | 2018-01-16 | 2018-01-31 | ValB  |
|        2 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-28 | ValB  |
|        2 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-31 | ValB  |
|        2 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 | ValB  |
|        2 | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-31 | ValB  |
|        2 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-30 | ValB  |
|        3 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 | ValC  |
|        3 | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-12 | ValC  |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
```

This view basically creates a record for each record in the table, but splitted by month, using the correct dates (especially minding the start and end dates that are not on the first or the last day of the month).
The one record without a To date (so it's still valid to this day), is rendered until the last day of the month in which I render the view, so at the time of writing, this is july 2018.

This is a simple example, but a solution will seriously help me along. I'll need this for multiple calculations, including proration of amounts.

Here's a table script and some insert statements that you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [From] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [To] SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    [Value] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Test ([From],[To],[Value])
VALUES 
('2018-01-01','2018-03-31','ValA'),
('2018-01-16',null,'ValB'),
('2018-04-01','2018-05-12','ValC');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the first row of your desired results, I guess "to" should be 2018-01-31 instead of 2018-03-31, right?

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry. Fixed it :-)

Comment: Do you have a numbers table?

Comment: No, all I have that is relatable to the desired result is a Date dimension. I will use this Date dimension for the proration of the amounts in the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate all months that might appear on your values (with start and end), then join where each month overlaps the period of your values. Change the result so if a month doesn't overlap fully, you just display the limits of your period.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2020-01-01'

;WITH GeneratedMonths AS
(
    SELECT
        StartDate = @StartDate,
        EndDate = EOMONTH(@StartDate)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, G.StartDate),
        EndDate = EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, G.StartDate))
    FROM
        GeneratedMonths AS G
    WHERE
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, G.StartDate) < @EndDate
)
SELECT
    T.Id,
    [From] = CASE WHEN T.[From] >= G.StartDate THEN T.[From] ELSE G.StartDate END,
    [To] = CASE WHEN G.EndDate >= T.[To] THEN T.[To] ELSE G.EndDate END,
    T.Value
FROM
    dbo.Test AS T
    INNER JOIN GeneratedMonths AS G ON
        G.EndDate >= T.[From] AND
        G.StartDate <= ISNULL(T.[To], GETDATE())
ORDER BY
    T.Id,
    G.StartDate
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 3000)
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you EzLo! And thanks for explaining, I can start using this right away :)

Comment: OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 3000) cannot be used in a view

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis good catch, in that case the OP should add the option on the query using the view (if necessary).

Answer (score 4):

Recursive *cte* is very simple way if you don't have a large dataset :

```
with t as (
    select id, [from], [to], Value
    from Test
    union all
    select id, dateadd(mm, 1, [from]), [to], value
    from t
    where dateadd(mm, 1, [from]) < coalesce([to], getdate())
)

select id, [from], (case when eomonth([from]) <= coalesce([to], cast(getdate() as date)) 
                         then eomonth([from]) else coalesce([to], eomonth([from])) 
                    end) as [To], 
       Value
from t
order by id;
```

Comment: You forgot about [to]. For id=3 should be 2018-05-12 not 2018-05-31

Answer (score 2):

@EzLo your solution is good but require setting 2 variables with fixed values.
To avoid this you can do recursive CTE on real data

```
WITH A AS(
    SELECT
    T.Id, CAST(T.[From] AS DATE) AS [From], CASE WHEN T.[To]<EOMONTH(T.[From], 0) THEN T.[To] ELSE EOMONTH(T.[From], 0) END AS [To], T.Value, CAST(0 AS INTEGER) AS ADD_M
    FROM
    TEST T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    T.Id, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(T.[From], -1+(A.ADD_M+1))), CASE WHEN T.[To]<EOMONTH(T.[From], A.ADD_M+1) THEN T.[To] ELSE EOMONTH(T.[From], A.ADD_M+1) END AS [To], T.Value, A.ADD_M+1
    FROM 
    TEST T
    INNER JOIN A ON T.Id=A.Id AND DATEADD(MONTH, A.ADD_M+1, T.[From]) < CASE WHEN T.[To] IS NULL THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ELSE T.[To] END

) 
SELECT
    A.[Id], A.[From], A.[To], A.[Value]
FROM
    A
ORDER BY A.[Id], A.[From]
```

Answer (score 2):

By using date functions and recursive CTE.

```
with cte as
(
Select Id, Cast([From] as date) as [From], EOMONTH([from]) as [To1],
COALESCE([To],EOMONTH(GETDATE())) AS [TO],Value from test

UNION ALL

Select Id, DATEADD(DAY,1,[To1]), 
CASE when EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY,1,[To1])) > [To] THEN CAST([To] AS DATE)
ELSE EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY,1,[To1])) END as [To1], 
[To],Value from cte where TO1 <>  [To]
)
Select Id, [From],[To1] as [To], Value from cte order by Id
```