# Insert a row for each month in the range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to make my table here in Oracle

```
  +----+------------+------------+
  |  N |    Start   |     End    | 
  +----+------------+------------+
  |  1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-05-31 | 
  |  1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-06-31 |
  +----+------------+------------+
```

Into, **as silly as it looks**  I need to insert one row for each month in the range for each in the first table

```
  +----+------------+
  |  N |    month|  |   
  +----+------------+
  |  1 | 2018-01-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-01-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-02-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-02-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-03-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-03-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-04-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-04-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-05-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-05-01 | 
  |  1 | 2018-06-01 | 
  +----+------------+
```

I been trying to follow [SQL: Generate Record Per Month In Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058429/sql-generate-record-per-month-in-date-range) but I haven't had any luck figuring out the result I want.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Only if you explained which rules lead from A to B ... Why are there 4 January rows, two February - May and only one June? What is N? Is it really 1 in both source rows?

Comment: I cant remember that in 2018 there were 3**1**.6.

Comment: What's the purpose of column `N`? It always have the same value.

Comment: @littlefoot sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

My *best guess* is that you want to show all *begining of months* that are in the interval `start` to `end` in your table.

```
create table t1 as
select date'2018-01-01' start_d, date'2018-05-31' end_d from dual union all
select date'2018-01-01' start_d, date'2018-06-30' end_d from dual;

with cal as
(select add_months(date'2018-01-01', rownum-1) month_d
from dual connect by level <= 12)
select  cal.month_d from cal
join t1 on cal.month_d between t1.start_d and t1.end_d
order by 1;

MONTH_D            
-------------------
01.01.2018 00:00:00
01.01.2018 00:00:00
01.02.2018 00:00:00
01.02.2018 00:00:00
01.03.2018 00:00:00
01.03.2018 00:00:00
01.04.2018 00:00:00
01.04.2018 00:00:00
01.05.2018 00:00:00
01.05.2018 00:00:00
01.06.2018 00:00:00
```

So probaly there is a cut & paste error in your expectation for January.

Some other points

- do not use reserved word as `start` for column names
- Use `DATE` format to store *dates* to aviod invalid entries such as `2018-06-31`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE. For example:

```
with
n (s, e, cur) as (
  select s, e, s from t
 union all
  select s, e, add_months(cur, 1)
  from n
  where add_months(cur, 1) < e
)
select cur from n;
```

Result:

```
CUR
---------
01-JAN-18
01-JAN-18
01-FEB-18
01-FEB-18
01-MAR-18
01-MAR-18
01-APR-18
01-APR-18
01-MAY-18
01-MAY-18
01-JUN-18
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=38e22148da9d61c810efa75b8d2f4214).